# Android, Display list of images one by one on imageview

Tags: android, eclipse, image, list, crash

I'm using eclipse for android, and made an app that have 2 image-views and a question in textview, so user have to click image that belongs to question...
but every-time the user clicks an imageview application shows two other images and another question..

What I made:

- a list with name of images,
- shuffle the list,
- take 2 other images from assets directory 3 second after imageview is clicked...

but on some phones I get this Crash :

in android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:490) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:358)
>   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
>   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:733)
>   at com.al.Play.MerFoton(Play.java:174) at
>   com.al.Play.mer(Play.java:154) at
>   com.al.Play.access$3(Play.java:132) at
>   com.al.Play$MyCounter.onFinish(Play.java:329)
>   at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Is the problem that I change alot of images in app, or something else ?**

Comment: Please post your code where you call `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that images are to big and file size too, I resized them with Image Resizer and now is working well..

Answer (score 0):

I am based in the next library:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

In the library using memory cache for save image and performance visualization for picture.